# Monad Transformers in an Interpeter

Tags: haskell, monads, interpreter, monad-transformers

I am encountering a problem with Monad Transformers, but I think it's helpful to include some context of how I got to the state I'm currently in, so I'll start with a rough explanation of my program:

The project is  an interpreter for a simple (toy) programming language. I have a monad that is used to represent evaluation. It has a definition that looks like:

```hs
type Eval a = ReaderT Environment (ExceptT String (State ProgState a))
```

This works quite nicely, and I can happy write an evaluation function:

```hs
eval :: Expr -> Eval Value
eval (Apply l r) = ...
eval ...
```

The Value datatype has a slight quirk in that I embed Haskell functions of type `Value -> EvalM Value`. To do this I added a generic type parameter to the definition, which I then instantiate with `EvalM`:

```hs
data Value' m
  = IntVal Int 
  ...
  | Builtin (Value' m -> m (Value' m))

type Value = Value' EvalM
```

Things were going well, but then I had to write a function that heavily interleaved code using the `Eval` monad with IO operations. This looked kinda horrendous:

```hs
  case runEval ({-- some computation--}) of 
    Right (val, state') -> do
     result <- -- IO stuff here 
     case runEvaL {-- something involving result --} of 
      ...
    Left err -> ...
```

The function had like 5 levels of nesting, and was also recursive... definitely ugly :(. I hoped adapting to use a Monad Transformer would be the solution:

```hs
type EvalT m = ReaderT Environment (ExceptT String (StateT ProgState m))
```

This refactor was relatively painless: mostly it involved changing type-signatures rather than actual code, however there was a problem: `Builtin`. Given a expression that was applying argument `x` to a value of the form `Builtin f`, the `eval` function would simply return `f x`. However, this has type `Eval Value`, but the refactored `eval` needs to have type-signature:

```
eval :: Monad m => EvalT m Value
```

As far as Fixing this (i.e. making it typecheck) is concerned, I can think of a couple solutions each of which has a problem:

1. Implementing some kind of analog to `lift` where I can take `Eval a` to `EvalT m a`.

   - **Problem**: I'm not aware of how to do this (or if it's even possible)
2. Changing the `Value` type so that it is indexed by an inner monad, i.e. `Value m = Value' (EvalT m)`.

   - **Problem**: now anything containing a `Value m` has to be
     parameterized by `m`. I feel that it would unnecessarily clutters up the type-signatures of
     anything containing a `Value`, which is a problem given the initial
     motivation to do this change was cleaning up my code.

Of course, there may be a much better solution that I haven't thought of yet. Any feedback/suggestions are appreciated :).

Comment: How about changing `Builtin` to contain a value of an ADT describing all possible built-in functions, rather than an actual function?

Comment: Your `EvalT` looks identical to your `Eval` to me...? Also, did you perhaps mean `type Value = Value' EvalM` (rather than `data ...`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might like the [`mmorph`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/mmorph-1.2.0/docs/Control-Monad-Morph.html) package.

```
-- since State s = StateT s Identity, it's probably also the case
-- that Eval = EvalT Identity, under some light assumptions about
-- typos in the question
liftBuiltin :: Monad m => Eval a -> EvalT m a
liftBuiltin = hoist (hoist (hoist generalize))
```

Alternately, you could store a *polymorphic* function in your value. One way would be to parameterize over the transformer.

```
data Value' t = ... | Builtin (forall m. Monad m => Value' t -> t m (Value' t)
type Value = Value' EvalT
```

Another is to use `mtl`-style constraints.

```
data Value = ... | Builtin (forall m. (MonadReader Environment m, MonadError String m, MonadState ProgState m) => Value -> m Value)
```

This last one, though verbose, looks pretty nice to me; I'd probably start there.